# Reason for No Print Output

Tags: python

```
a = 1
b = []
while a <= 600851475143:

    if 600851475143  % a == 0:
        b.append(a)
    a += 1

print b
```

I'm trying to print the factors of 600851475143 as a list by using this loop, but nothing gets printed.
Any explanation?

Comment: Which python version are you using? 3.x or 2.x? The loop may be taking too long

Comment: Suppose Python were able to do a million iterations of the loop each second.  How long do you think it would take to do over 600 billion iterations?  Hint:  it would take 1000 seconds (over 16 minutes) to do 1 billion iterations.

Comment: I am using version 2.7

Answer (score 0):

The loop takes too much time. A PC can operate about 100000000 instructions per second. So your loop need about 4 hours or more to print the result.